# Manually Trigger Upload within fineUploaderDnd

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I have a problem. I have `autoUpload` set to false within `$('element').fineUploaderDnd();`

I can drag and drop files just fine. However, I can't seem to figure out how to manually trigger the upload. I have tried both of the following:

```
var uploader = $('#droppable').fineUploaderDnd(/*{ ... }*/);
uploader.fineUploaderDnd('uploadStoredFiles'); //Doesnt work
uploader.fineUploaderDnd('addFiles', handleUploads.fineUploaderFiles); //Also doesnt work
```

Note that `handleUploads.fineUploaderFiles` is an array of the 'File' objects the plugin returns to me `.on('processingDroppedFilesComplete')`

They both give me errors saying they don't support that. I've also tried various methods of using both the Dnd thing for drag/drop and the normal jquery fineUploader for 'addFiles' but that also doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines aren't going to work:

```
uploader.fineUploaderDnd('uploadStoredFiles'); //Doesnt work
uploader.fineUploaderDnd('addFiles', handleUploads.fineUploaderFiles); //Also doesnt work
```

Because you can only call the `uploadStoredFiles` and `addFiles` methods on instances of FineUploader. It appears you are calling these methods on instances of the DnD module.

There are no such options in the standalone Fine Uploader DnD module. The standalone drag-and-drop module doesn't upload anything.  It is meant to be used alongside FineUploaderBasic mode instance (note that you can use it outside of Fine Uploader entirely if you want to). This module is provided for FineUploaderBasic users who want to integrate drag & drop support easily into their app.  If you are using FineUploader mode, drag & drop is already integrated for you, however.

To achieve this in basic mode

First, add an instance of FineUploader:

```
var uploader = $("#uploader").fineUploader({ uploaderType: 'basic' /*, ... */ })
```

Next, add an upload button:

```
var uploadButton = $("#upload-button").on('click', function () {
    $("#uploader").fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
});
```

Then, instantiate your drag and drop module (note that this is separate from FineUploader's instance!):

```
var dnd = $('#droppable').fineUploaderDnd({
     /* custom options */            
}).on('processingDroppedFilesComplete', function (event, files) {
    uploader('addFiles', files); //this submits the dropped files to Fine Uploader
});
```

For reference, please see the following:

- Difference between [FineUploaderBasic](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/modes/fineuploaderbasic.html) & [FineUploader mode](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/modes/fineuploader.html)
- [Documentation on the standalone DnD module](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/drag-and-drop.html)
- [API for FineUploaderBasic mode](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/fineuploaderbasic.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't realize the DnD module is supposed to be used in combination with the Basic module. In terms of your answer, what is `fineUploaderBasicInstance` supposed to be? I tried setting that to both $('#uploader') as well as $('#uploader').fineUploader({uploaderType: 'basic'}), but neither seem to work.

Comment: @Jeff, my fault. Instead of `fineUploaderBasicInstance` it should be either `uploader` or `$("#uploader").fineUploader`

Comment: turns out it was a little different for the jQuery version, I had to use `$('#uploader').fineUploader('addFiles', files);`. That worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.